# Can i Copy PDF file text to another text file in Android?

Tags: android

all i want to ask something about dealing pdf in android.actually i want to EDIT(add some stuffs ) PDF and want to save it..So,how can i achieve this??is there library is present in Android to EDIT PDF file??or can i copy text from PDF all the time and paste it into newly txt file and again converted that txt file to new PDF file?????

Anyhow i want to EDIT PDF and save it..give some ideas or samples for the same...

Thanks in Advance---

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is go to http://market.android.com and search for "edit pdf" which brings back many results.  Such as:

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.mobisystems.editor.office_registered

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.dataviz.docstogoapp

But this isn't a programming question, so it doesn't belong here.

Comment: i have seen app. which u hv given me..for PDF you can just view it n we can max. or min view..where it is to EDIT PDF???

Answer (score 1):

I see Adobe Reader for Android, but not an edition of the full Adobe suite.

I think it's unrealistic to expect to edit on a phone.

Comment: then anyhow it is not possible to Edit PDF in Android???or copy text from it n make another PDF???

Comment: Seriously you shouldn't answer such questions, especially not by posting a comment as an answer.

Comment: @octavian i just want to know whether it is possible or not??